# Does Sigma Jump Higher than Other Heroes?

Tags: overwatch

A while back, Blizzard added a patch to Overwatch that normalized jump heights across all characters. This meant that characters could exploit certain map features (ex. first point Anubis, some heroes could jump up to the first semi-high ground spot, using some of the terrain). This was fixed at some point, and a lot of those spots were lost.

However, with the introduction of Sigma, who floats off the ground, it seems that this jump-height restriction has been changed or ignored. I have a much easier time getting onto the high ground jump spot on first point Gibraltar, as well as being able to do that Anubis jump, among other things. It could be anecdotal evidence, which is why I'm asking;

Can Sigma jump higher than other Overwatch heroes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is no, Sigma jumps the same height as other characters.

Of course, the height of each hero affects your perspective of the game. Sigma is the tallest hero in the game, while Torb is the shortest, but they can both clear the same obstacles.

Here are a couple of places in the practice range where you can test this for yourself. Firstly, the practice targets. Heroes can consistently 'nearly' make it on top of these, but will always slip back down again unless they have a significant speed boost before jumping (such as Soldier 76's sprint).

[image: Training room practice targets]

The other place is the stairs between the spawn room and the roaming bots, with the railings and piece of blue tarp. If you stand at the bottom and try to jump onto the upper level, you'll never clear it. standing on the first step, you'll almost make it up, and on the 2nd stair, you will always make it up.

[image: Training room stairs]

Comment: Bravo, thanks for doing some detailed investigation on this!